# how to split strings and bind them as header for gridview

Tags: c#

I have a string list:

```
List<string> rows = new List<string>();
```

Now, rows has data like this:

```
countryname~population
india~12,211
china~23,22,223
usa~45,454
japan~34,343,232
```

I need to bind this data in gridview like countryname, and population as header for gridview

```
countryname  population 
    india       12,211
    china      2322223
    usa          45454
    japan     34343232
```

any help would be 
 great thank you

Comment: The commas are somewhat erratic. Are they just typos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through your list of string, store the data of country and population in a datarow and add that datarow in the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

From where are you getting this list? A better way would be to have a class with two properties say country and population. Then use a collection of objects of this class and get rid of the string list.

With this list too you can create a list of similar objects using ForEach loop and then bind the GridView.